# Is it possible to construct such a function in analytical form?

Tags: analysis, functions

Suppose $f\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=\sin(x)$

Is it possible to find $f$ in closed form, or any other forms so as to visualize $f(x)$ on $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$?

Is it possible to prove the existence and uniqueness of such functions?

Comment: [Functional square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root)

Comment: see this [question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/45608/33248) on MO.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks for the link and for saving me a lot of work! I had just figured out the coefficients of that series up to $x^9$. The plots of the iterates $T_k(T_k(x))$ of the truncated series look a bit wonky, when $|x|>2$. That may be an artefact, and may just mean that truncation and iteration don't mesh well. I can share the plots if there is any interest. Will Jagy's question at MO does have more material than I can possible produce.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.physics.miami.edu/~curtright/TheRootsOfSin.pdf).

Comment: And [this](https://arxiv.org/ct?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdx.doi.org%2F10%252E1088%2F1751-8113%2F44%2F40%2F405205&v=058edd1e).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

I guess that this is a difficult question. This functional equation is said to define the *iterative square root* of the RHS, of which the Babbage equation

$$f(f(x))=x$$

is the prototype.

[When a particular solution is found, such as $f(x)=-x$, more solutions are obtained as $f(x)=\phi^{-1}(-\phi(x))$, for instance $f(x)=\exp(-\ln(x))=\dfrac1x$ or $f(x)=\sqrt{-(x^2-1)+1}=\sqrt{2-x^2}$. Anyway, I don't know if a similar property holds for other RHS functions.]

You can approach this particular case by observing that $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is qualitatively close to a particular solution, as it yields a "lowered" sinusoid.

[image]

The maximum amplitude can be adjusted to $1$ by introducing a coefficient,

$$f(x)=a\sin(x)$$ so that
$$f(f(x))=a\sin(a\sin(x)).$$ With $$f\left(f\left(\frac\pi2\right)\right)=a\sin(a)=1$$we get a suitable value $$a\approx1.1141571408719$$

[image]

To get a perfect match, this function should be composed with a slightly non-linear one, on which insight can be obtained by observing the plot of $\arcsin(a\sin(a\sin(x)))$.

[image]

There is no doubt that there must exist a suitable function which is piecewise smooth. One can probably find good numerical approximations from least-squares solutions of

$$f(f(x))=P(\sin(P(\sin(x))))=\sin(x),$$ where $P$ is a low degree polynomial of indeterminate coefficients, by identification of Taylor coefficients or by expressing equality at a number of arbitrary $x$ values.